# Why doesn't forward iterator have addition assignment operator?

Tags: c++, iterator, forward-list

I know `std::forward_list<T>::iterator` doesn't have a compound-assignment operator (`operator+=`). But why is that?

I'm asking this for three reasons:

1. wouldn't this operator advance the "forward" iterator like `operator++()` ?
2. Isn't there a helper function `std::advance()` that does the same thing ?
3. I'm implementing my own forward list (for learning) and I want to know what's wrong with `operator+=()`.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain what's wrong with this question ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
std::advance(it, n);
```

(Declared in `<iterator>`.)

The point is that compound-assignment operators are only provided when the operation has O(1) cost. Since incrementing a forward iterator has linear cost, it's better to make this explicit.

If you want a new value that's the result of repeated increments, use:

```
auto it2 = std::next(it1, n);
```

Comment: I was expecting someone to answer this question by "because the standard says so" I'm glad (for OP) that you didn't. +1.

Comment: Is `it += 2` really less explicit than `advance(it, 2)`?

Comment: @Barry: Well, it was considered so by the committee. It's not so much that `+= 2` is not understandable, but people didn't feel comfortable that this could be an expensive operation. Iterators are a generalization of pointers, and when you see `+= 2` you think pointer arithmetic first and foremost.

Comment: @Barry: (I've heard stories of iterators that connect to databases...)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah I don't doubt that that's the right reason - but it's just a little... weird.

Answer (score 5):

> But I don't know why ?

Well a forward iterator can only be advanced forward one unit at a time.  `+=` is generally used to go more than one unit at a time.

> wouldn't this operator advance the "forward" iterator like `operator++()` ?

It would but you could use it like `iterator += 10` which would leave you to believe it is going to advance 10 places instantly.  Instead it would have to be 10 separate `++` calls.

> Isn't there helper function std::advance() that does the same thing ?

Yes there is but it explicitly states that it is multiple `++` calls unless you are using a random iterator.

> I'm implementing my own forward list (for learning) and I want to know what's wrong with operator+=()

Your iterator should conform to the standard definition of a forward iterator.

Comment: Additional problem: what if you add negative number?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Well that could be solved by using an unsigned type for the function parameter ;)  Unfortunately std::advance also allows that.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know why ?

There is certain contract that different category iterators must follow. Description can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) You can see what contract is for [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) category, where `std::forward_list<T>::iterator` belongs to, and there is no `r += n` operation which is for [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)